# Can an RBM solve this Autoencoder example?

Tags: neural-networks, restricted-boltzmann-machine, autoencoders

I'm currently trying to debug my own RBM implementation by applying it to an autoencoder exercise I've done before. In this exercise I feed 8-dimensional unit vectors to 3 hidden nodes and force the network to learn a compressed binary representation, i.e.:

```
####### visible ########    ## hidden ##
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] ->  [0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] ->  [1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] ->  [0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0] ->  [1, 1, 0]
          ...                   ...
```

With the three hidden nodes the network should be able to memorize / distinguish 2^3 = 8 different input vectors. Of course this requires heavy overfitting and the autoencoder only succeeded when I disabled the regularization term in the weight update rule.

Now when I train the RBM on this example, it is only able to reconstruct 3 vectors. All other inputs get scrambled, i.e.:

```
####### visible ########    ## hidden ##  #### reconstruction ####
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] ->  [0, 0, 0] -> [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] ->  [1, 0, 0] -> [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] *correct
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] ->  [0, 0, 1] -> [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] *correct
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0] ->  [0, 0, 0] -> [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0] ->  [0, 1, 0] -> [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0] *correct
          ...                   ...                 ...
```

At first I thought that I had a bug in my RBM implementation, so I've tried others (e.g. this [implementation by edwin chen](https://github.com/echen/restricted-boltzmann-machines)), but the results were similar.

I've heard that the binary units of an RBM also act as regularizers. Is this the reason why the example doesn't work well? Or should I continue searching for bugs in my code?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally sure but yes, binary RBM models comes with a builtin regularizer. When you compare the activation value in one unit with a number sampled from a uniform distribution you're limiting the amount of information this unit can transmit from $[0, 1]$ to $\{0, 1\}$ and this acts as a regularizer.

ref: A Practical Guide to Training Restricted Boltzmann Machines
https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hinton/absps/guideTR.pdf

Maybe if you train for a very long time you can achieve the same result as the auto encoder.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Hinton's guide was what I was referring to, but I missed the link here. I also think, that this is the reason, but it doesn't seem to improve with longer training. I trained for 100,000 epochs and there was almost no improvement after ~20,000 epochs.